# How do I derive this energy equation?

Tags: energy, plasma-physics

The Energy Equation is given as follows.

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + \textbf{v} \cdot \nabla p + \gamma p \nabla \cdot \textbf{v} = (\gamma -1) \eta \lvert \textbf{j} \rvert ^2$$

How do I derive it? And what do LHS and RHS of this equation denote?

Comment: I think you have something wrong here, unless I am mistaken about what each term represents.  For instance, what does $\rho$ represent?  Some sort of energy density?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be $p$ (pressure) and not $\rho$. I edited the equation above.

Answer (score 2):

In general, energy loss or gain in a plasma may be due to many different effects: for example, radiation, ohmic resistance, and so on.

Here, you were given an energy equation that was written assuming that ohmic resistance dominates other energy sources and sinks.  Hence, the loss/gain function $L$ can be simplified to the ohmic resistance term $-(\gamma-1) \eta |\mathbf{j}|^2$.  $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index; $\eta$ is the plasma resistivity; and $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you explain why is there a $\gamma -1$ term? I mean what is its significance?

Comment: @000, from thermodynamics, the equation for the rate of change of internal energy density is $\frac{de}{dt} = -L = \frac{\rho^\gamma}{\gamma-1} \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{p}{\rho^\gamma}\right)$.  Under the adiabatic assumption (ideal MHD), this would be 0, so people often cancel out the initial $\frac{\rho^\gamma}{\gamma-1}$ factor.

Comment: But of course, you cannot do this if the energy is not constant. In ideal MHD, there is an energy equation analogous to your form, but with the loss term equal to 0.  It is derived from the starting point $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{p}{\rho^\gamma}\right) = 0$.  If you start from $\frac{\rho^\gamma}{\gamma-1} \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{p}{\rho^\gamma}\right) = -L$ instead, you will find that the $\gamma-1$ term is kept throughout the derivation.

Comment: @Thorondor - Are you sure about what $\eta$ represents?  I would naively assume it represents electric resistivity, not magnetic diffusivity.  That is, I don't think it's proportional to the resistivity, I think it IS the resistivity.  Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: @honeste_vivere I am used to $\eta$ representing diffusivity, e.g. [these notes](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/research/cfsa/people/valery/teaching/khu_mhd/KHU_mhd_handout.pdf) and [these notes](http://indico.ictp.it/event/a06220/session/45/contribution/26/material/0/0.pdf). Usually if you want to talk about the resistivity per se, you would instead use the conductivity $\sigma$.

Comment: This is ultimately an issue of conventions.  You could certainly use $\eta$ to represent the resistivity instead, and apparently some authors do that.  FWIW, though, a quick Google Scholar search shows many more results for "plasma conductivity" than "plasma resistivity."

Comment: I'm used to a resistivity tensor because conductivity requires that the resistivity tensor be invertible, but yes, in some ways it's a conventional jargon issue.  The reason I made the point is mostly to avoid confusion, since the electric fields are doing the work and this is the dissipative term in the energy equation.

Comment: @honeste_vivere That's a good point. I'll edit the answer.